# android webview not load mobile version

Tags: android, webview

I'm having a problem with my android webview app. The app run normal in some devices but it won't load mobile version when I use in Sony Acro S, it's always load web version. For first time, I think maybe it is my android version (4.1.2) but I tried in different device with same os version (4.1.2) and the result is the device load mobile version not web version. Here's my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

{
    private WebView browser;

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    WebIconDatabase.getInstance().open(getDir("icons", MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());

    // set javascript and zoom and some other settings
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    browser.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    // Below required for geolocation
    browser.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    //parse
    Parse.initialize(this, "", ""); 
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();


    //enable all plugins (flash)
    browser.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

I try use this code,

```
browser.getSettings() .setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```

I still got same result. Can anybody help me to solve my problem ? Thank's

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the actual user agent for your device. It'll vary depending on Android version etc, so never hard-code this value, you have to read it:

```
//get the UA of the current running device:
String userAgent = browser.getSettings().getUserAgentString() ;
//set the UA of the webview to this value:
browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Comment: Not working...Still loading desktop site...my code:  wvDetails.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); String userAgent = wvDetails.getSettings().getUserAgentString() ;
        wvDetails.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
        wvDetails.loadUrl(item.getLink());